# getFile Method invokes error callback with weird error code (1000) - eventhough the file exists

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem){
  fileSystem.root.getFile(localPath, { create: false }, function(fileEntry) {
      doSomethingGood();
  }, function(err) {
      alert(err.code);
  });
});
```

the file specified in localPath exists in my Filesystem. I still get the error Callback. It alerts the code: `1000`. This is strange, because, according to the dcoumentation, the errorcode should be one of those in `FileError` which equal 1 to 12 (http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileError). So what does the errorcode `1000` want to tell me? And why is the error Callback thrown if the file exists?[image]

Comment: do you get any other errors in your logs (stack trace)? error `1000` is defined as `UNKNOWN_ERR` in `FileUtils`

Comment: also, did you request access to the file system?

Comment: yes:             window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem) {

Comment: @benka: no, I did not get any other errors. The problem still prevails :(.

Comment: Might help to know what localPath actually contains?

Answer (score 0):

Code 1000 seems to be used for invalid addresses.

Check out the following examples (extract from my log file, on an Android device):

```
Read /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.my.app/cache/repositories/0001/summary.jpg  not found 
=> FileError code: 1

Read cache/repositories/0001/summary.jpg  not found 
=> FileError code: 1

Read file:///repositories/0001/summary.jpg  not found 
=> FileError code: 5

Read file:///cache/repositories/0001/summary.jpg  not found 
=> FileError code: 5

Read //cache/repositories/0001/summary.jpg  not found 
=> FileError code: 1000

Read /cache/repositories/0001/summary.jpg  not found 
=> FileError code: 1000

Read //repositories/0001/summary.jpg  not found 
=> FileError code: 1000

Read /repositories/0001/summary.jpg  not found 
=> FileError code: 1000

Read //storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.my.app/cache/repositories/0001/summary.jpg  not found 
=> FileError code: 1000
```